# Replicate Apple Reminder's behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfielddelegate

If you've used the Reminders app on iOS 5, you've probably noticed how hitting return on your keyboard while adding an item creates another one in the next row.
What is the best manner to implement this? Should the `TableViewController` conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` or should the custom cell be in charge of it? If the latter, how should I inform the `TableViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do the former. A controller is a controller; a cell is a view (cf. MVC).